# WebStorm can't connect cucumber.js gerkhin to actual step definitions

Tags: webstorm, cucumberjs

I have a test suite that works fine when ran from the command line. In WebStorm, however, all my steps in the .feature file, WebStorm says they cannot find the step definitions. I have moved them to a step_definitions folder as well, in which when I hover over the highlighted "undefined step reference" in WebStorm it seems to find them but it still cannot connect the two.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what WebStorm version do you work with? Looks similar to [WEB-13940](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13940), but it's fixed in 9.0.3

Comment: That looks like part of the problem.  I upgraded and now it is working but it is only identifying steps written as regular expressions, not those in quotes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem it was solved by simply restarting WebStorm, so that may be worth testing for anyone stumbling upon this question like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is related with issue WEB-15600 cucumber.js support only sees steps written as regular expressions

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15600

Comment: Yes, I opened that ticket